# Audio quality issues with mpd

Tags: audio, mpd

I have been using mpd for a long time now and absolutely love it.
However, I recently added a few video files to the mpd database. Now I understand mpd won't play the video files, I don't want it to.

But when mpd plays the audio track of the video file, there is a lot of static noise in the output. My other audio files work perfectly with mpd. As do these video files in other players like mplayer and vlc.
This leads me to conclude that the audio track on these videos is not of bad quality. There is something wrong in the way mpd handles them.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong and how I can resolve it?
Yes, I know I could rip the audio tracks out of my video files and play them using mpd, but I would rather fix this issue with mpd than do that. Just a matter of choice.

Comment: So you just complain that audio player doesn't play video files as perfect as you want? That's amazing =)

Comment: The audio track of my video files. There should be absolutely no problem with an audio player playing the audio track of a compatible video file.

Comment: Have you tried other players like MPlayer ?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that in my original post. In VLC and MPlayer they work perfectly as expected.